# What happens if I don't set a port in 8051 as input or output?

Tags: assembly, 8051, mcu

I am a beginner and recently started so please bear with me if its a dumb question.
So in 8051 MCU we use
`MOV P1, #00H` or `MOV P1, #0FFH` to set the port as input or output respectively.
My Question is, if I don't specifically mention a port is input or output, will a program still work ?
I am trying to implement a lookup table, in which P1 will take the input (0-9) and display its square
in P2.

```
        ORG 0000H
        MOV DPTR,   #TBLE
        MOV P1,     #0FFH
        MOV P2,     #00H
        ;Begin Transfer
NEXT:   MOV A,      P1
        MOV R1,     A
        MOVC A,     @A+DPTR
        MOV P2,     A
        CJNE R1,    #00H,NEXT
        SJMP $


        ORG 0100H
    TBLE:   DB  00H,01H,04H,09H,16H,25H,36H,49H,64H,81H
        END
```

Answer (score 3):

> So in 8051 MCU we use `MOV P1, #00H` or `MOV P1, #0FF` to set the port as input or output respectively.

This is already wrong:

You use `MOV P1, #00H` to set all pins of the port to low. If all pins of `P1` are ***out***puts and want to set all pins to high, you would also use `MOV P1, #0FFH`.

At the 8051 MCU, (nearly) all pins are open-drain outputs: You can pull a pin whose output value is "high" to "low", so you output "high" to a pin if you wish to use it as input.

However, you have to set output pins to "high" from time to time; otherwise the pins would always be "low" which makes absolutely no sense:

You could simply use the minus pole of your voltage supply instead of using a microcontroller!

> ... if I don't specifically mention a port is input or output ...

The reset values of `P0`...`P3` are `0FFH`.

This means that these registers have the value `0FFH` after starting the MCU. If you don't explicitly write to these registers, they will keep the value `0FFH`.

This also makes sense:

If the initial value would not be `0FFH`, some pins would be "low" in the few microseconds before the `MOV P1, 0FFH` instruction.

If you have an input and the value coming from outside is "high", you would have a shortcut if `P1` contained another value before `MOV P1, 0FFH` is executed.

Comment: `The reset values of P0...P3 are 0FFH.` Could you please give source at what page on the datasheet or manual or standard or reference?

Comment: @Unknown123 For the "original" Intel chip, you could look at the [MCS-51 family user manual](http://web.mit.edu/6.115/www/document/8051.pdf), page 2-9. I doubt that this differs for other 8051 compatible chips (Atmel, Infineon ...): A reset value that is not `0FFh` would mean that you cannot use the corresponding pins as inputs (at least if it is an open-drain pin) because the microcontroller would shortcut the input.